# I get a "�" on my page, PhpMyAdmin shows "é" not sure how to fix it

Tags: php, mysql, html

in PhpMyAdmin it shows up as 'Petite-Réserve" but when i echo it to a webpage it shows as "Petite-R�serve" MyISAM latin1_swedish_ci is the database encoding and `<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` is at the top of the page. Not sure how to fix this. I'm allowing users to input text and users are French and English. I'm using Google Chrome and it shows up as a question mark in a triangle. Any ideas?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the right content-type on the page - since you are outputting latin1 (as defined in your database), try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

`iso-8859-1` is the encoding name for latin1.

Comment: Any reason you'd use latin1 over utf-8?

Comment: @eyelidlessness: The database is latin1, so emitting latin1 makes a bit of sense here.

Comment: @eyelidlessness - Because this is the encoding of the data in the database.

Comment: Nope. Its a default. Should i change the DB to use "utf-8"?

Comment: @Keverw - You can, and probably should. However, you will need to convert all the data within the columns as well.

Comment: Okay. So i would want "utf8_general_ci"?

Comment: Thanks. I change. had the DB and works great. Had to reenter data but its all sorted now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a different encoding to output data to that is has been saved in, you have to encode or decode the data beforehand. Try

```
utf8_encode($value);
```

in this case.
Alternatively, change the encoding of your HTML to iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

Often best to decide on one charset and not to mix them. If you mix them you will have to convert between them. mbstring can help there. Best to switch your database to UTF-8. It is more flexible then the latin variations.

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP response headers sent by your webserver. One of the headers might include the content-type, and that value in your http headers might not match the UTF-8 encoding declaration you've got in HTML.